# Java mail incorrect formatting

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am sending mail using java mail. I can not use mime type as HTML. When i am sending mail it is looking bad because of spacing. How to fix this?

**Text  I am sending** 
[image]

**How it appears in mail**

[image]

Comment: You should set mime type as HTML. If your HTML code is proper, you will not suffer from spacing problem.

Comment: What kind of mail client? Do you use spaces or tabulators?

Comment: Are you using tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: I can not use mime type as HTMl, i am using space only, i am not using tabs

Comment: @lakshman String text = "SLNo                 FIRST NAME           LAST NAME           EMP NO             STATE  \n"
            + "1.                   ABCDEFGHI            FGHI                123456789          KARTYQT\n"
            + "2.                     EFG                 RTY                  5678990          TIKHSYH\n"
            + "3.                   HTG                  ABC                      9453             KH  \n";

Answer (score 4):

The question isn't how you're sending it, the question is what are you using to display it?

You can line up everything nicely assuming you're using a fixed width font, but if the mail reader displays it using a variable width font, all your alignment will be lost.  You don't get to control what font is used to display the message you're sending.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, the expectation is that mail with a content-type of `text/plain` should be rendered with a fixed-width font. There are clients which do not obey this convention, though, and there is nothing you can do about that (except in your own account, if the client allows you to configure this).

The workaround is to use a content-type with a stricter definition, or send email with a hyperlink to a web page which renders the way you like (or, if you are in a position where you can do this, miff your users by forcing them to use a client you choose). All of these options have drawbacks from a usability point of view, but for content which does not make sense without proper formatting, you can probably find a reasonable compromise.